# React-Javascript: Las imagenes no se cargan en firefox, pero en chrome si

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs, firefox

el problema es simplemente ese. Busque en varios sitios y no consigo solucionarlo. Ademas probé en opera y tiene el mismo problema que firefox.

En chrome las imágenes se ven a la perfección, les dejo el código.

```
 render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src={"https://icon-icons.com/icons2/1412/PNG/48/comics-spiderman-cam_97492.png"} />Home </a>

        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li className="nav-item active">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" onSubmit={() => { console.log(this.state.id)}}> >
            <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" value={this.state.id} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <button className="btn btn-light" type="submit" >Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <Body valorId={ this.state.id}/>
      {alert(this.state.id)}
      </div>

    );
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. ¿revisaste si te está entregando algún error en la consola de desarrollo de firefox? ¿cuál es el HTML generado? ¿que te sale visualmente? mas info

Comment: Hola!! muchas gracias por responder, no tengo ningún error en la consola, visualmente me sale el icono de  que la imagen no se cargo.

Comment: En la pestaña de Red/Network debería aparecerte un 404 o similar